# Apache2 VirtualHost no domain

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I need help to set up my VirtualHost settings. My idea is it to run some applications and other stuff on my server (IP "123.456.789" I don't have a domain yet). Therefore I wanna call my apps / sites like this:

- 123.456.789/app1
- 123.456.789/index2
- 123.456.789/testenviroment/app5
- 123.456.789/gitlab

List item

and so on.

I don't know how I can accomplish my goal with the VirtualHost...

I would be very grateful for any help and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the Alias directive:

```
Alias /app1 /path/to/your/app1
<Directory "/path/to/your/app1">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All

    # you can put any other directives/options here
</Directory>
```

You can put this inside any VirtualHost tag you have,
and you can have as many Alias declarations as you need,
just be careful not to use duplicate aliases.